# responsive div containing resized image to keep aspect ratio

Tags: css, responsive

I am using bootstrap to constuct a responsive menu bar containing 180*180 div, which in turn contains a 100*100 img, that i have resized to 53*53. I am a noob in terms of bootstrap, and am not advanced in the use of CSS either.
What I want is that the div starts off as 180*180 on a large screen, and resizes keeping it's square shape, AND still maintaining the centered img (which I reckon can stay at 53*53 - but if I can make it also resize I would be very happy as we may change the image to be bigger in the future).

[Here is a fiddle of the work so far](https://jsfiddle.net/PixelGnome/trcs0amj/3/)

Can anyone help? I have spent hours playing with bootstrap, and looking at other examples, and my boss is starting to think I'm a moron, which I may well be, but I really want to get it working...
here is my code :

```css
.new-menu-item {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  color: #fff;
}
img {
  width: 53px;
  height: 53px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
a {
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #990000;
  display: block;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
a.active {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="new-menu">

  <div class="col col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 new-menu-item">
    <a href="" class="new-menu-link">
      <p>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
        <br />Menu Item 1
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 new-menu-item">
    <a href="" class="new-menu-link">
      <p>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
        <br />Menu Item 2
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 new-menu-item">
    <a href="" class="new-menu-link">
      <p>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
        <br />Menu Item 3
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 new-menu-item">
    <a href="" class="new-menu-link active">
      <p>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
        <br />Menu Item 4
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 new-menu-item">
    <a href="" class="new-menu-link">
      <p>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
        <br />Menu Item 5
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 new-menu-item">
    <a href="" class="new-menu-link">
      <p>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
        <br />Menu Item 6
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```